How to make SSH more sensible to failures?
SSH sometimes appears in state when process is not finished, there is command log from a server on a screen but in fact connection failed – user can't make any commands, command line does not respond.
Or the same with SSH tunnels – process is running, but connection is lost.
How to detect this case and fail ssh process to start it again or show alarm? Maybe there is some parameters for ssh binary?

"process is running, but connection is lost" – {Client,Server}Alive{Interval,CountMax} will probably help.

Possibly this isn't a problem with ssh but with the remote server.  Maybe it is overloaded or out of memory?  You haven't well described the problem.  If available, it might help to ask a system administrator to diagnose it for you.

As Kamil Maciorowski said, I needed ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax options. These options had very big values on my client machine so ssh client didn't know that connection had been lost.
After setting these options like below in ~/.ssh/ssh_config I had what I want.
ServerAliveInterval 10
ServerAliveCountMax 2

